# Change variable in other class and update view

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

First: Iam new to swift/swiftui

Problem: trying to update a published var:String in a observableOjbect class from a function. That var is used to for a switch later in a view.

I followed some inputs i found on my google research, but it doesnt work for me and i cant figure out why.

I tried @ObservedObjects, @EnvironmentObject, @StateObject, but i cant figure out how the string can be changed - in the view it always stays "x". getBotResponse(message: messageText) is called from another view / textField. My goal is to let the bot answer text, or with prepared buttons or images. depending on the input, the string should change to a "keyword" which is used as switch in the view to show other "view" modules i prepared.

```
class ChatBotVariables: ObesrvableObject{
    @Published var answerCase: String = "x"
    @Published var showFurtherContent: Bool = false
}

func getBotResponse(message: String) -> String {
   let tempMessage = message.lowercased()

   @ObservedObject var tempAnswerCase = ChatBotVariables()

   if tempMessage.contains("textA"){
     tempAnswerCase.answerCase = "text"
     return "some text for BotAnswer"
   }else if tempMessage.contains("textA"){
     tempAnswerCase.answerCase = "video"
     tempAnswerCase.showFurtherContent.toggle()
     return "some other text for BotAnswer"
   }else{
     tempAnswerCase.answerCase = "questionbox"
     tempAnswerCase.showFurtherContent.toggle()
     return "something else"
   }
}
```

```
struct ChatBot: View {


//happyBar
@State var _ratio = 60.0;
@State var _start : Bool = false;

@State private var messageText = ""
@State var messages: [String] = [""]
@State public var messageProperty = "Y"

@State private var botWriting = false
@State private var textInputEnabled = false

@ObservedObject var vm = MainMessagesViewModel() //reference to MMVM

@StateObject var cbl = ChatBotVariables()
@State var _case: String = "text"
//&@EnvironmentObject var cbl: ChatBotVariables

//@StateObject var showFurtherContent: Bool = false

init() {
    initChatbot()
}

var body: some View {
    
   NavigationView {
       VStack {

           ScrollView{
               
               ForEach(messages, id: \.self){ message in
                   if message.contains("[USER]"){
                       let newMessage = message.replacingOccurrences(of:"[USER]", with: "")
                       
                       HStack{
                           Spacer()
                           Text(newMessage)
                               .padding()
                               .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                               .background(.blue.opacity(0.8))
                               .cornerRadius(10)
                               .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                               .padding(.bottom, 10)
                       }
                   }else{
                       
                       HStack{
                           Text(message)
                               .padding()
                               .background(.gray.opacity(0.15))
                               .cornerRadius(10)
                               .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                               .padding(.bottom, 10)
                           
                           Spacer()
                       }
                       
                     
                   }
               }.rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
               
               
               if cbl.showFurtherContent {
                   
                   switch cbl.$answerCase{
                        case "emoji":
                            print("asdf4")
                        break;
                        case "video":
                            print("asdf2")
                        break;
                        case "yesno":
                            print("asdf")
                           break;
                        default:
                           ()
                        break;
                   }
                   cbl.showFurtherContent.toggle()
               }
                
           }.rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
           .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.10))
   
           if(messages.count > 1){
               let mCount = messages.count
               Text("count: \(mCount) answer: \(cbl.answerCase) Property: \(messageProperty)")
           }
           
           HStack {
               if botWriting{
                   Image(systemName: "ellipsis.bubble.fill")
                       .font(.system(size: 26))
                       .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
               }
           }
           
           Spacer()
          
           // Show / Hide Text input bar
           if textInputEnabled{
               VStack{
                   HStack{
                       TextField("Text eingeben", text: $messageText)
                           .padding()
                           .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                           .cornerRadius(10)
                           .onSubmit{
                               sendMessage(message: messageText)
                               //switchHappyBar() // Debug
                           }
                           .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                       
                       Button{
                           sendMessage(message: messageText)
                           //switchHappyBar() // Debug
                       }label:{
                           Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
                       }
                       .font(.system(size: 26))
                       .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))
                   }
                   
                   HStack{
                       Button{
                           // Show Options For text
                       }label:{
                           Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
                       }
                       .font(.system(size: 26))
                       .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

                       Spacer()
                       
                       Button{
                           textInputEnabled.toggle()
                       }label:{
                           Image(systemName: "keyboard.chevron.compact.down")
                       }
                       .font(.system(size: 26))
                       .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 50))
                       
                       Spacer()
                   }
               }
               
           }else{
               HStack{
                   Button{
                       textInputEnabled.toggle()
                   }label:{
                       Image(systemName: "keyboard")
                   }
                   .font(.system(size: 26))
                   
               }
           }
       }
       .navigationBarHidden(true)
   }
}

func initChatbot(){
    messages.append("Hallo \(vm.chatUser?.email ?? ""), wie geht es dir heute INIT?")
}

func sendMessage(message: String){
    withAnimation{
        messages.append("[USER]" + message)
        self.messageText = ""
        botWriting.toggle()
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1){
        withAnimation{
            messages.append(getBotResponse(message: message))
            botWriting.toggle()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Move ObservedObject into View, it should be there

Comment: I have also an @ObservedObject reference in the view (to access the variable) - but it has to be changed within the function above (getBotResponse)

Comment: then you need to inject reference to that one in view via arguments

Comment: Do you please have an example to make it more clear? The swift syntax is challanging in my opinion

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui). Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Hy lorem ipsum, thanks for your input - I added the ChatBot View script below. I try to describe the problem: Basically the ChatBot view should check the ChatBotVariables class for changes the getBotResponse function generates trough inputs, the user is sending from a text field or via buttons (I created some swiftui files which have different buttons) my only problem is, that I can't bring the communication / variable synchronization / overwriting to work between those 3 files. I think the solution is simple for a pro, but im a swift(ui) beginner and my research results didn't help

Comment: Furthermore: The "if cbl.showFurtherContent { ... }" area in the ChatBot code for example causes a "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'" error - don't see the reason for that tbh